# Help with some Bukowski syntax

Tags: syntactic-analysis, poetry

I'm working to translate some Bukowski and got confused with the syntax of "Advice For Some Young Man In The Year 2064" (https://www.pinterest.com/pin/751678994049154743/) to the point that the meaning is unclear to me.

Specifically, in the second stanza, he writes:

"be careful less the onion blind the eye

or the snake sting

or the beetle possess the house

or the lover your wife

or the government your child..."

1.It looks to me like a comparison meaning: "be careful less **than** the onion blind the eye or.." but I'm really not sure.

2.Also, is the subject-verb disagreement in "onion-blind", "snake-sting" something common?

3.Lastly, it is not clear to me what the  implied verb is in e.g., "the government your child". My guess is that it should be read as "the government **cares about** your child".

What's your take on that?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't is a typo?  Doesnt the author mean "lest the onion blind the eye"?

Comment: Centaurus has the measure of the first one: *lest*. As for the second, the "government your child" clause is governed by the verb *possess*, like all the final three clauses.

Comment: or the lover (possesses) your wife, or the government (possesses) your child

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"less" is a mistake: possibly a typing-error. It should be "lest":

> **lest**
> *[formal]* With the intention of preventing (something undesirable); to avoid the risk of.
>  *Example: he spent whole days in his room, wearing
> headphones lest he disturb anyone.* ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lest))

As you see from Lexico's example, following "lest" the subjunctive mood is needed: "lest he disturb" rather than "lest he disturb**s**." Nowadays we usually say, "**in case** something happens" or "**for fear of** something happening." "Lest something happen" is more concise, but as Lexico says, 'formal'.

In the last two lines, the word "possess" - though not repeated - is understood from the context. It is like -
"I love you."
"And I you."
The omission of superfluous words in this way is called 'ellipsis'.

We could rewrite the lines like this:

be careful in case the onion blinds the eye
or the snake stings
or the beetle possesses the house
or the lover [possesses] your wife
or the government [possesses] your child..."

Without "lest" we don't need the subjunctive, but the poem becomes less elegant. And without the ellipses (plural of ellipsis) the repeats are dull. And "in case" isn't quite the same as "lest".

Comment: Unless this is a dialectical use of "less" for the word "lest", which unfortunately I can't find any evidence for.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Yes - it would be hard to track that down. I don't remember hearing it in the UK but it would be a hard one to spot. I remember some cowboy film where they said 'lessen', but I don't remember whether it meant 'lest' or 'unless'. The only two printed versions of the poem I've found have either less or unless, neither of which work. Maybe Bukowski just got it wrong. Like Browning with his 'tw*t'!

Comment: ...and his 'slughorn', come to think of it.

Comment: @PeterShor: [This](https://bukowskiforum.com/threads/advice-for-some-young-man-in-the-year-2064-a-d.340/) appears to be a scan of the original publication (containing "less") side-by-side with a later revision where it's replaced with "unless". Make of that what you will :)

Comment: @psmears: Actually, Google books shows that the original publication contained "unless". The revised version appeared in *The Pleasures of the Damned*, a collection of Bukowski's poetry that appeared over a decade after Bukowski's death. I don't know whether the differences between the two versions are Bukowski's changes or not. (Some of them, such as "dressed as a man" → "dressed as a uniformed man", seem too arbitrary to be an editor's changes.)

Comment: @PeterShor: You're right, I accidentally switched "less" and "unless" while writing my comment, sorry about that! (Do you have a link to the original in Google Books? I can see the *Epos* edition in the index, but it won't show me the content there...)

Comment: @psmears: you can Google lines from the poem in quotes, and Google Books will tell you if they're in the *Epos* edition, although it won't show you them.

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks... I'd managed to do that (was the only way I could find the right edition - title search was hopeless!). I was just hoping you'd managed to find a way to persuade it to show the actual content :)

Comment: Enlightening! Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this does not make sense; there is an error and "less" should be read "unless".

This is the word found in [this copy of the poem](https://bukowskiforum.com/threads/advice-for-some-young-man-in-the-year-2064-a-d.340/).

There is an ellipsis of the verb "possess" in the last two lines.

- or the lover possess your wife
- or the government possess your child.

Comment: No, *unless* doesn't work there at all.

Comment: The page you link to also has the correct version, and some remarks on how the first one is at least less (sic) pleasing. I can't help but think some clumsy editor thought *less* was wrong but guessed wrong as to what the poet meant.

Comment: @PeterShor  et al  - According to the SOED, "unless" did have the meaning "lest" in the 16th century; it is obsolete now, but isn't it conceivable to think that, assured of legitimacy of use  through poetic license, Bukowski could have consciously used an obsolete word? It does coincide perfectly.

Comment: @tripleee: I saw that page. Yes, I think that's possibly it: neither of them got it right :-) – Old Brixtonian